# Install WSO2 Stratos 2.0 on single node?

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos

I have setup WSO2 Stratos 2.0 on single node using following documentation http://docs.wso2.org/display/Stratos200/OpenStack I have downloaded wso2s2-openstack-1.0.1, extract zip file, and follow the instructions in the README.txt file.
But I don't understand this step in Readme.txt file:

> Open up the security rules in openstack for the following ports which
>   are from ./con/setup.conf
>       22, 443, 8280, 4103, 4100, s2_db_port, agent_https_port, agent_http_port, bam_port, elb_port, agent_clustering_port,
>   sc_cluster_port, elb_cluster_port,
>        bam_reciever_port, bam_reciever_secured_port, cassandra_port, userstore_db_port, s2_db_port,

in Openstack install section

Can you give me more detail about this step?

Thank you very much! :)

---

In fact, I want to build a private cloud on my VM.
In my scenario, I use OpenStack (Havana) as IaaS and WSO2 Stratos 2.0 as PaaS. But I can find any document on infrastructure level about deploy Stratos on IaaS. 
WSO2 have document on installing Stratos, but indeed I am very confuse how OpenStack and Stratos combine with each other?
Cloud is very new to me and I am learning. 
So, could someone give me the right direction to learning or some useful link for me started.

And another question: install Stratos on OpenStack controller or compute node or both?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing Stratos on a single node, for prototyping or testing purposes, you probably don't need Openstack in the first place. Any (virtual) machine would do.

If you use Openstack, it happens that all the ports in your virtual instances are closed by default. If you need specific ports to be accessible to that server, you must enable them, creating security rules in the corresponding security group where this machine belongs.

If using nova-network, this would open 8280 in the 'default' group, for any address:

```
nova secgroup-add-rule default tcp 8280 8280 0.0.0.0/0
```

See instructions at:
http://docs.openstack.org/network-admin/admin/content/enabling_ping_and_ssh.html